# I don't know how to use a function that takes no input and displays no output

Tags: c, function, printing, cs50

So I'm trying to output the winner from a selection of people you can vote from and display the person with the most votes. To print the winner, I was given a function meant to display the winner once a separate function had tallied up the votes, and it looks like this;

```
void print_winner(void)
```

I don't understand how to use this. If the function isn't supposed to accept input from my tallies or display output, then how is it supposed to work? I don't understand how to use a function like this.

Comment: Can you add a link to the actual problem statement?

Comment: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/psets/3/plurality/

Comment: You just call it with no arguments and don't assign the result: `print_winner()`

Comment: You can use global variables, which is a bad habit so I don't see the point of that exercise if that's the goal.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The description of the program says that: **Next, the file defines a global array of candidates, where each element is itself a candidate**

Comment: Functions don't have to be *pure*. They can produce side effects, such as IO or access/modify some global state.

Comment: Sounds like this function uses global variables, which is not great, but is an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand how to use this. If the function isn't supposed to accept input from my tallies or display output, then how is it supposed to work? I don't understand how to use a function like this.

IMHO, you are confounding *displaying* with *returning*.  A function displays some value by means of calling another function (a more or less fixed function implemented in the C language and available for you to use it: `printf()` is one of these)  You will need the documentation of `printf(3)` in order to do this;  On the other side, a function *returns* a value to be used in your calculations by means of fixing a  type to the value returned (this is the `void` return type appearing first in the function declaration meaning *no return type*.

A function that doesn't require parameters, can still be useful, as it can operate on global variables in order to execute some algorithm.  When a function requires no arguments, it must still be called with a (now empty) argument list between parenthesis, and it must be declared by using `void` as the parameter list declaration.  As in:

```
void print_winner(void)
{
     printf("The winner is %s(%d)\n", winner, winner_score);
}

/* ... */
    if (event_finished) print_winner();
```

You'll see in this example that we are checking that the event has already finished in the `if` statement, and if so, we call the `print_winner()` function to just display the winner.